# VBA Error 3134 Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have taken on supporting/upgrading a MS Access system.  I have created a form that copies records from existing items to newly created items for the same tables.  I am doing this for 2 tables.  The code works importing records for the first table but gives me the error for the second table.  The code is as follows:

```vbs
Private Sub cmdImportMaterials_Click()
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Procedure : cmdImportMaterials_Click
    ' Author    : kelly
    ' Date      : 26/05/2014
    ' Purpose   : Import materials to the current task from existing materials associated to the selected task.
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '

    On Error GoTo cmdImportMaterials_Click_Error
        Dim iCboTaskID As Integer
        Dim iImportTaskID As Integer
        Dim sMaterialsSql As String
        Dim sMatAddSql As String
        Dim db As Database
        Dim rstMat As Recordset
        Dim rstMatAdd As Recordset
        Dim sInsertMatSql As String
        Dim sInsertMatAddSql As String
        Dim sCust As String
        Dim iJobNo As Integer



    If IsNull(Me.cboTaskID.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a task to import materials from"
    Else
        iCboTaskID = Me.cboTaskID.Column(0)
        sCust = Me.cboTaskID.Column(1)
        iJobNo = Me.cboTaskID.Column(2)
        sMaterialsSql = "Select * from MaterialRequisition Where TaskID = " & iCboTaskID & ";"
        sMatAddSql = "Select * from MaterialRequisitionAdditional Where TaskID = " & iCboTaskID & ";"
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rstMat = db.OpenRecordset(sMaterialsSql)
        Set rstMatAdd = db.OpenRecordset(sMatAddSql)

        If rstMat.RecordCount = 0 And rstMatAdd.RecordCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no materials to import. Please select a task with materials."
        Else
            iImportTaskID = Forms![Task List].ID
            Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to import the materials from " & sCust & "; Job #: " & iJobNo, vbYesNo)
                Case vbYes
                    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

                    'Add selected Additional materials to current task
                    If Not rstMat.EOF Then rstMat.MoveFirst
                    Do While Not rstMat.EOF
                        sInsertMatSql = "INSERT INTO MaterialRequisition ( TaskID, MatterialsListProductID, ItemQuantity, " _
                            & "Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit) " _
                            & "VALUES (" & iImportTaskID & ", " & rstMat("MatterialsListProductID") & ", " & rstMat("ItemQuantity") _
                            & ", """ & rstMat("Comments") & """, " & rstMat("Category") & ", """ & rstMat("Description") _
                            & """, """ & rstMat("ItemCode") & """, """ & rstMat("Supplier") & """, " & rstMat("Price") _
                            & ", """ & rstMat("Unit") & """);"
                        Debug.Print sInsertMatSql
                        DoCmd.RunSQL (sInsertMatSql)
                        rstMat.MoveNext
                    Loop
                    rstMat.Close
                    Set rstMat = Nothing

                    'Add selected Additional materials to current task
                    Debug.Print sMatAddSql
                    If Not rstMatAdd.EOF Then rstMatAdd.MoveFirst
                    Do While Not rstMatAdd.EOF
                        sInsertMatAddSql = "INSERT INTO MaterialRequisitionAdditional ( TaskID, ItemDescription, ItemQuantity, " _
                            & "Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit) " _
                            & "VALUES (" & iImportTaskID & ", """ & rstMatAdd("ItemDescription") & """, " & rstMatAdd("ItemQuantity") _
                            & ", """ & rstMatAdd("Comments") & """, " & rstMatAdd("Category") & ", """ & rstMatAdd("Description") _
                            & """, """ & rstMatAdd("ItemCode") & """, """ & rstMatAdd("Supplier") & """, " & rstMatAdd("Price") _
                            & ", """ & rstMatAdd("Unit") & """);"
                        Debug.Print sInsertMatAddSql
                        DoCmd.RunSQL (sInsertMatAddSql)
                        rstMatAdd.MoveNext
                    Loop
                    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
                    rstMatAdd.Close
                    Set rstMatAdd = Nothing
                    Set db = Nothing

                Case vbNo
                    MsgBox "No selected" 'Do nothing
                End Select
        End If

    End If

Exit_cmdImportMaterials_Click:
    Exit Sub

cmdImportMaterials_Click_Error:

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure cmdImportMaterials_Click of VBA Document Form_frmMatReqListImport"

    Debug.Print "#" & Err.Number, Err.Description, "cmdImportMaterials_Click", "Form_frmMatReqListImport"

    Resume Exit_cmdImportMaterials_Click

End Sub
```

The SQL produced for each Sql string is as follows:
(The field types are the same for both statements except MatterialsListProductID is numeric and ItemDescription is text)

`sInsertMatSql`:

```
INSERT INTO MaterialRequisition ( TaskID, MatterialsListProductID, ItemQuantity, Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit) VALUES (2956, 131, 300, "", 15, "M8 X 65 FEET", "FET-00000000131", "SPRINGLOK                               ", 2.18, "each");
```

`sInsertMatAddSql`:

```
INSERT INTO MaterialRequisitionAdditional ( TaskID, ItemDescription, ItemQuantity, Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit) VALUES (2956, "4MM WIRE", 1860, "METRES", , "", "", "", , "");
```

Comment: What error is being produced and which line is it being given on?

Comment: Hi Gareth
As per Christian's answer below

Answer (score 0):

From your first query, I can see that the `Category` and `Price` columns have numeric data types (you are inserting numeric values).

In your second query, you're trying to insert **nothing** into these columns (not even `NULL` - nothing):

```
... VALUES (2956, "4MM WIRE", 1860, "METRES", , "", "", "", , "")

                                             ↑             ↑
                                            here        and here
```

If you don't want to insert anything into these columns, try one of the following solutions instead:

1. Omit the columns completely (in the list of named columns *and* the list of values)
2. Insert `NULL` if the columns are nullable
3. Insert `0`

Comment: Hi Christian thanks for responding.
Is there any syntax for number types that will make the value null if there is no value?  If Null then null seems cumbersome. 
thanks

Comment: Just insert `NULL` *(if the columns allow it)*: `VALUES (2956, "4MM WIRE", 1860, "METRES", NULL, "", "", "", NULL, "")`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are doing a lot of looping (inefficient) and "SQL glue-up" (ugly and error-prone) when all you really need to do is something like this:

```vbs
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "INSERT INTO MaterialRequisition ( TaskID, MatterialsListProductID, ItemQuantity, " & _
        "Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit) " & _
        "SELECT [newTaskID] AS TaskID, MatterialsListProductID, ItemQuantity, " & _
        "Comments, Category, Description, ItemCode, Supplier, Price, Unit " & _
        "FROM MaterialRequisition WHERE TaskID = [oldTaskID]")
qdf!oldTaskID = iCboTaskID
qdf!newTaskID = iImportTaskID
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
```

That will copy all of the [MaterialRequisition] records from [oldTaskID] and insert them into the table under [newTaskID].

Comment: hi Gord thanks for your help definitely cleaner.  
When I try run the code I get "error #91 Object variable or With block variable not set" @ the line: Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", _.
What am I missing?  Do i need to set the the DB im using? (not sure if access defaults to the projects DB)
thanks

Comment: Make sure that you have `Set db = CurrentDb` before you try to use `db.CreateQueryDef`.